# re-order array2 so items in array1 are at top

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one is a subset. I need to re-order the larger array so that all the items from array one are at the top of it.

```
array('c', 'e');
array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
```

I want the 2nd array to look like this:

```
array('c', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g');
```

"c" and "e" are at the top of it.

Comment: array_unique(array_merge($ar1, $ar2)) maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `usort` and move the elements up if the other array contains the element:

e.g:

```
$a = array('c', 'e');
$b = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');

usort($b, function($x, $y) use($a) {
    return in_array($x, $a) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This won't take into consideration the order of `$a`, but will allow duplicate elements (if required).

Answer (score 0):

array_merge: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$a1 = array('c', 'e');
$a2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
$am = array_merge($a1, $a2);
```

After reading the requirements, this is the correct approach:

```
$a1 = array('c', 'e');
$a2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
$a2 = array_diff($a2, $a1);
$am = array_merge($a1, $a2);
```

Comment: Oh wait I see I read it incorrectly. This answer will only merge with first array items on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 = array('c', 'e');
$a2 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
$a3 = array_unique(array_merge($a1, $a2));
```